# Gradle Generated APK name always has "app" and not my app name

Tags: android, gradle

The following build script generates three APK's but doesn't seem to include the app's name.

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig)
    }
  }
}

def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    if (output.zipAlign) {
      def file = output.outputFile
      def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
      output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }

    def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
    def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
    output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
  }
}
```

This generates:

```
app-development-release-null-1.apk
app-live-release-null-1.apk
```

How can I remove the "null" and replace "app" with my app's actual name?

**Update**
I fixed the null by adding in a versionName to the top of the gradle file. For some reason it was missing but still can't seem to fix the "app" string and replace it with my app's name.

Comment: See this one https://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/producing-better-named-android-apks-with-gradle/ it may help you

Answer (score 0):

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'appName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ways, this should give you some hint.

I added application name in `root build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    // other class path.

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

 ext {
    androidApplicationId = 'com.sample.myproject'
    androidVersionCode = 1
    androidVersionName = "1.0"
    androidAppName= 'myproject'
  }
}
```

Then in app `project build gradle`, add `def baseName`:

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidApplicationId")
    versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
    versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")

    def baseName = globalConfiguration.getAt("androidAppName")
    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", baseName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName);
  }
...
```

You will get generated apk with app name like this:

```
myproject-1.0-debug.apk
```